# How do I create an apache vhost that catches domains not hosted on the server?

Tags: dns, apache2, vhosts

What would an apache2 vhost look like that catches domains that aren't explicitly hosted on my web server in any other vhosts?

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    virtual host config goes here
</VirtualHost>
```

This virtual host will catch requests coming in on port 80 with a host name that doesn't match any other virtual host.